# Evolutionary programming

Tags: programming-languages

I just watched a pretty cool [ted talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/danny_hillis_back_to_the_future_of_1994.html) by Danny Hillis dated 1994.

At one point in the video, he talks about "evolutionary programming", i.e. he asks the computer to generate hundreds of programs by generating random sequences of commands, then tests to see how well each program sorts numbers. He keeps 10% of the programs that sorts numbers the best, then generates a next round of programs based on the 10% that did well and repeats as many times as he wants to, to eventually generate the ultimate sorting program.

Are there tools/programming languages out there that do this? E.g. given certain constraints, generates C code that best satisfies those constraints.

I've visited some wikipedia articles related to "Evolutionary Programming"; there seems to be a lot of theory there, but it doesn't seem easy to find something you can just play with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple and general free downloadable source is [TinyGP](http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/staff/rpoli/TinyGP/) implemented in Java.
By the way.. for more details on this you should search information about "genetic programming" instead of "evolutionary programming". it is all a bit confusing because there are so many subfields of evolutionary computation with small diffrences in the names like "genetic algorithms", "evolutionary strategies", "evolutionary programming", "genetic programming"...
but i think what you're talking about is actually genetic programming

Answer (score 3):

One practical example:

> [Csmith](http://embed.cs.utah.edu/csmith/) is a tool that can generate random C programs that statically and dynamically conform to the C99 standard. It is useful for stress-testing compilers, static analyzers, and other tools that process C code. Csmith has found bugs in every tool that it has tested, and we have used it to find and report more than 400 previously-unknown compiler bugs.

Comment: It has nothing to do with evolutionary computing - there is no selection at all, any random program in Csmith is 100% valid.

Comment: That depends on the driver executing Csmith — automatic selection can happen based on whether the generated code triggers a detectable compiler bug; new output can be generated either from scratch or by performing mutations on prior output.

Comment: that's interesting, I'll give it a try. I've only used fully random generated code for testing before.

Answer (score 3):

Classic examples are [Tierra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tierra_(computer_simulation)) and [Avida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avida).

A relevant area is hardware evolution and evolutionary robotics, see [this page](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/Users/adrianth/ade.html) for example.

There's also a nice [book](http://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=3481) about evolutionary computing in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

This book/tutorial use Ruby for evolutionary programming.

http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The field of evolutionary computation that generates programs is called Genetic Programming (GP). 
GP simulates the biological evolution of a population of individuals, through many generations. Usually, an individual is a program (or its representation, typically as a tree data-structure) and its chances of surviving and reproducing are measured in terms of its performances in solving a task.

Nowadays you can not generate practical production code for everyday tasks, honestly. Rather, GP and many other Machine Learning techniques are investigated in modern research and are used by very big companies (i.e. Google, Facebook, etc.). In fact, the GP approach is very useful when you know what you want the objective-program to do (i.e., you know the output given the input) but you have no idea of how (or it's simply difficult for you) to write the code by yourself.

In order to properly understand the topic, you probably want to write the evolutive engine from scratch and play with it. It's perfectly fine to write the code starting from a theoretical description. That's the best way to learn how these things work, rather than using some "pre-builded software", imho.
Also, I suggest you to start with Genetic Algorithms (GA), because they are generally simpler. In fact, in GA you usually evaluate the genotype of the individuals, i.e. the bits composing them, while in GP you may want to transorm trees into programs, execute them, look at the output and finally measure their performances (not so straightfoward, uh?). Take a look at this: http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/creating-a-genetic-algorithm-for-beginners/3.

The lab where I did my Master's thesis is proving that GP has very good performances in generating regular expressions from examples of text extraction. They build a GUI in order to play with their engine: http://regex.inginf.units.it/demo.html. They also shared the engine code on github: https://github.com/MaLeLabTs/RegexGenerator. 
Finally, a friend of mine coded some funny visual experiments using GP and GA (Genetic Algorithms) in his blog. Take a look: http://www.nicassio.it/daniele/gp/enviroment/, http://www.nicassio.it/daniele/gp/santaclaus/.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be a nay sayer, but we did some test with evolutionary programming and found that on a lot of problems, exhaustive search was faster.

There are closely related fields liked Genetic Algorithms, which I have used to make robots walk etc.  I used GALIB for that. It is probably ancient now.

While the idea is "cool" the best approach might be to use a combination of evolutionary techniques plus learning (i.e. reinforcement learning).

This is more like how humans learn anyway. There is long term evolution making gradual experiments, plus learning that fixes things up and adapts the system to the environment.

But, evolution just takes too long to be efficient.

Comment: Like MA, then? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memetic_algorithm

Answer (score -1):

Probably the most versatile program for creating evolutionary programs would be Assembler. This is the only language that I know of that has the ability to overwrite other programs and change its own code. You might want to have a look at the old Core Wars programs - a different or more up to date version of one of these programs might be able to evolve and beat out competition. Furthermore, you have the possibility of survival of the fittest, insofar as there are a limited number of directories.

Comment: With assembler you can do everything, but it doesn't means that it is easy to use... And surely it is not the best solution (there are a lot of more powerful programming languages, like LISP or C, that can be used for these purposes).